# Interact with Google Chrome bookmarks from a Cocoa App

Tags: cocoa, google-chrome

I am trying to write a Cocoa App that needs to manipulate Chrome Bookmarks. What is the best way to get access to Chrome bookmarks to allow insertion, deletion, updating.

Answer (score 1):

Chrome stores its bookmarks in a simple text file called Bookmarks which (on OS X) is stored in the user home directory, `$HOME/Library/Application Support/Google/Chrome/Default/Bookmarks`. It's a JSON file for which I guess there are several libraries API available. (like [this one](https://github.com/stig/json-framework/))

If you mean to directly manipulate the bookmarks stored in Google cloud, check [this](http://www.mmartins.com/mmartins/googlebookmarksapi/) link.

Comment: Chrome bookmarks are different from Google bookmarks right? So the link is kinda tangential. If you manipulate the file and chrome tries to do the same, wont there be a race?

Comment: You can synch your Chrome bookmarks with Google bookmarks. When you create a bookmark in Chrome, the Bookmarks file will be modified at once and of course at startup the file is opened, but other then these I don't think it's touched at all, so you probably won't have concurrency issues.

Comment: Every time there is a modification, the file is touched, my guess is there will be all kinds of races. I am looking for a better solution.